# Combine two queries into single radius search for mapping

Tags: mysql

I need some help combining these queries into one if possible. The user would enter in the zipcode in a from. The return should be zipcode and distance.

Table structure:

zipcode | state | latitude | longitude

```
SELECT latitude,
        longitude
 INTO   @latitude, @longitude
 FROM   zipcodes
 WHERE  `zipcode` = 36101
 LIMIT  1;

SELECT zipcode,
       ( 3959 * Acos(Cos(Radians(@latitude)) * Cos(Radians(latitude)) * Cos(
                                   Radians(longitude) - Radians(@longitude)) +
                              Sin(Radians(@latitude)) * Sin(Radians(latitude)))
       ) AS
       distance
FROM   zipcodes
HAVING distance < 10
ORDER  BY distance
```

**My Solution**
I just ended up doing these as 2 separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

Please try, if you might these approach:

```
SELECT zipcode,
       ( 3959 * Acos(Cos(Radians(A.sel_latitude)) * Cos(Radians(latitude)) * Cos(
                                   Radians(longitude) - Radians(A.sel_longitude)) +
                              Sin(Radians(A.sel_latitude)) * Sin(Radians(latitude)))
       ) AS
       distance
FROM   
    zipcodes,
    (
       SELECT 
          sel_latitude,
          sel_longitude
       FROM   
          zipcodes
       WHERE  
          `zipcode` = 36101
       LIMIT  1
    ) AS A
HAVING distance < 10
ORDER  BY distance;
```

I hope it helps in some way

Comment: Awesome, I'll check it out shortly. Thanks for the response!

Comment: It didn't work but I just ended up doing an additional query and its all working out find.

Comment: Hi. I'm really sorry - I had a mistake in the internal query - it's now edited, corrected and should work. Here you can find working SQL-Fiddle for this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94224/2 . Regards.